# How to store selected language in ngx-translate?

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I have created an application using this example: https://stackblitz.com/github/ngx-translate/example.

The application works fine, but when if I switch to French and refresh my browser, it is set to default English again.

In the app.component.ts constructor, I have the below code:

```
constructor(public translate: TranslateService) {
 translate.addLangs(["en-US", "fr-FR", "de-DE"]);
 translate.setDefaultLang("en-US");
}
```

Is there a way to keep the selected language even when the page/browser is refreshed?

Comment: According to this issue, there is no built-in way: https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/71 but you can implement it by yourself using the localStorage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to explicitly tell `TranslateService` which language to use via `this.translate.use('en')`.

Depending on whatever you are constructing here, this will run for every page reload, thus the Translate Service will always use the language you're setting here.